# How to add a back button in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history, gatsby

How can I add a back button which is not reloading the page?

At the moment I have this, which works, but with a full reload:

```
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

<button onClick={browserHistory.goBack}>Back</button>
```

But I would rather use Link from React Router to go back without having to reload the page.

Comment: It looks like you have the right idea from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915173/react-router-go-back-a-page-how-do-you-configure-history

Comment: Does clicking the browser back button also cause a page reload? They should work the same way.

Comment: The back button works without the page reload when I came to the page through a <Link> component. When I arrived at the page through a link in a Markdown file hitting the back button reloads the page. The same applies when I use the browser's back button.

Comment: Yeah, that's unfortunately how browsers work. If the last path change was from a reload then hitting the back button will also reload regardless.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kyle

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up using in my React components:

```
<button onClick={this.context.router.goBack}>Back</button>
```

If you also want to transition between pages written in Markdown without a page refresh, you need to modify the `wrappers/md.jsx` file:

Thanks to Scott Nonnenberg for the [blog post](https://blog.scottnonnenberg.com/practical-gatsby-js/) explaining how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of reach-router supports this. You just need to add the following code to create a back button

```
                        <button onClick={()=>navigate(-1)}>Back</button>
```

Cheers

Comment: you could add  `import { navigate } from "gatsby";`