# Can you go backwards through react-router v4 hashHistory?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, html5-history

Wondering how to go back to a previous route in a react web app using hashRouter instead of browserRouter in react-router v4?

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915173/react-router-go-back-a-page-how-do-you-configure-history) question which doesn't seem to work even though it says no browser mixin needed (plus I think its talking about an older react-router version) however, every other solution I've seen depends on browserHistory.

Is it possible with hashHistory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.props.history.goBack()
```

Taken from the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915173/react-router-go-back-a-page-how-do-you-configure-history#33850354)

It is a function call.

Comment: I used this into my homepage  this.props.history.push({ pathname: '/Classlist'})  and   this.props.history.goBack() into Classlist page it work great but when   this.props.history.push({ pathname: '/classdetail'}) when i used this.props.history.goBack() into classdetail page it's redirect to exact path that is '/'

Answer (score 1):

Well in my case i did like that :

```
import withRouter from "react-router-dom/es/withRouter";
import React from "react";

class Component extends React.Component {
  goBack() {
    this.props.history.go(-1);
  }
  ...
}    
const WrappedComponent = withRouter(Component)
export default WrappedComponent;
```

withRouter give us access to history in props of component, but i'm not sure is this way is correct

Comment: It doesn't work. Fails with an error saying: Component is not a variable.

Comment: Yes indeed it because I did mistake with names :)