# this.props.history.goBack() changes URL in browser to just / but Route exact path="/" does not get called

Tags: reactjs, meteor, navigation, react-router

I'm using React and React Router on a Meteor JS app.

I have a `Route exact path="/"`  that works if I use `this.props.history.push('/')` but if I use `this.props.history.goBack()` even if the URL changes to just `http://localhost:3000/` the `Route exact path="/"` does not get called:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => {
              console.log('React exact path /')
            return mainpage
          }} />
```

How can I fix this?
or should I just always use push?
or should I just use replace?

Comment: Did you wrap your component withRouter? Which router are you using ?

Comment: yes i'm using withRouter . ....  export default withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(App))

Comment: You should use BrowserHistory in the history field. 
const BrowserHistory = require('react-router/lib/BrowserHistory').default;
 <Router history={BrowserHistory}>...

Comment: hi how? can you give a more specific example please?  Thank you...

Comment: Can you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30938949/5562701

Comment: I just realized that i'm using react-router-dom and not react-router...if i installed react-router would it conflict?  can I also use BrowserHistory with react-router-dom?