# How to navigate to previous screen in with React Routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am opening a modal on click of a menu item by redirecting the user to a new route. I am changing the route when the modal opens. I want to redirect to the previous screen whenever the user clicks on close or cancel button.
I am using the below code-

```
onCancel = () => {
  props.history.goBack();
}

<Modal open={true}, onClose={onCancel}> </Modal>
```

My component is a functional component and I can see goBack() in my history object, however, this does not work and user is not able to navigate to previous screen.
I am trying to achieve this through redirect. Please suggest me if there is anyway.

```
React version- 16.8.2
react-router-dom- 4.3.1
```

Comment: Did you try with `BrowserHistory`?

Comment: @techie questie can you share your complete code or in sandbox?

Comment: Please check a similar post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915173/react-router-go-back-a-page-how-do-you-configure-history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915173/react-router-go-back-a-page-how-do-you-configure-history) Thanks,

Comment: would need to see your routes and where/how you are calling redirect within react.