# React conditional based on URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a `navbar` and a **Contact** button in it. I would like to change this **Contact** button to a **Back** button based on the URL.

If the url is `localhost:5000/` then let it be **Contact**, if the url is `localhost:5000/about` then it should be **Back**.

Is this possible? I'm not sure which syntax can do this.

```
{localhost:5000/ && <button>Contact</button>}

{localhost:5000/about && <button>Back</button>}
```

This is obviously incorrect, I just wonder if there is a similar approach.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router go back a page how do you configure history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30915173/react-router-go-back-a-page-how-do-you-configure-history)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `v5.1` or onwards of `react-router`, you can opt to use the [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) hook in functional components. This will be useful in determining which path the user is currently at - then you can assess whether to render "Back" or "Contact". I recommend using ternary operator for this.

```
import { Route, useLocation, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <>
      ...
      
      {location.pathname === "/" ? <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link> : <Link to="/">Back</Link>}<br/>

      ...
    </>
  );
}
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-williamson-489gl?file=/src/App.js

---

If you are using a lower version of `react-router` or using a class based component, you can use [`withRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter). The logic will be very similar in that you will get access to your `location` object, but `withRouter` is a higher-order component

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Navbar` component has access to the router's props, you can do this:

```
// ./components/Navbar.js
import React from 'react';

function Navbar({ location }) {
 
   if (location.pathname === "/about") {
       return <button>Back</button>
   }

   return <button>Contact</button>;
   
}

export default Navbar;
```

If the React version you're using is 16.8 or higher, consider using Hooks:

```
// ./components/Navbar.js
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function Navbar({ location }) {

   let location = useLocation();
 
   if (location.pathname === "/about") {
       return <button>Back</button>
   }

   return <button>Contact</button>;
   
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/) for that(obviously you can do using window object). But react router is better:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

const Navbar = ({ location }) => {
 
   if (location.pathname.includes("about")) {
      // you can check using equality also (location.pathname === "/about")
       return <button>Back</button>
   }

   return <button>Contact</button>;
   
}

export default withRouter(Navbar);
```

**Note**: You only **withRouter** if your component does not have access to react router props other wise it will work without it if it has access to location props